# Enabling PHP's gzopen function on an AWS server

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

On a WordPress site I manage, I am attempting to run a full backup using a plugin called Updraft Plus. The backup will not proceed passed a table called wp_nm_mc_forms. The penultimate line of the log file (included below) says:

```
0416.971 (0) PHP function is disabled; abort expected: gzopen.
```

I believe this means that on my AWS server, the PHP function, gzopen, used for opening a compressed file, has been disabled. Is this correct? If so, how can I turn it back on?

**Log file**

```
0000.000 (0) Opened log file at time: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 22:04:11 -0500 on http://www.expandintheusa.com
0000.011 (0) UpdraftPlus WordPress backup plugin (https://updraftplus.com): 1.11.17 WP: 4.3.1 PHP: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 (Linux lucid 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686) MySQL: 5.5.35 Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) safe_mode: 0 max_execution_time: 900 memory_limit: 1024M (used: 3.8M | 4M) multisite: N mcrypt: N LANG: C ZipArchive::addFile: Y
0000.017 (0) Free space on disk containing Updraft's temporary directory: 12157.6 Mb
0000.032 (0) Tasks: Backup files: 1 (schedule: daily) Backup DB: 1 (schedule: daily)
0000.052 (0) Requesting semaphore lock (fd)
0000.067 (0) Set semaphore last lock (fd) time to 2015-11-24 03:04:11
0000.073 (0) Semaphore lock (fd) complete
0000.093 (0) Backup run: resumption=0, nonce=5811117ce9f5, begun at=1448334251 (0s ago), job type=backup
0000.109 (0) Scheduling a resumption (1) after 300 seconds (1448334551) in case this run gets aborted
0000.125 (0) Checking if we have a zip executable available
0000.141 (0) Creation of backups of directories: beginning
0000.170 (0) Beginning creation of dump of plugins (split every: 500 Mb)
0000.819 (0) Total entities for the zip file: 650 directories, 4229 files (0 skipped as non-modified), 65.2 Mb
0000.854 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 100 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0000.869 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 200 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0000.887 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 300 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0000.904 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 400 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0000.926 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 500 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0000.930 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (4.8 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (501) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 0 Kb)
0002.392 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 600 files added (on-disk size: 2746.3 Kb)
0002.424 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 700 files added (on-disk size: 2746.3 Kb)
0002.448 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 800 files added (on-disk size: 2746.3 Kb)
0002.469 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 900 files added (on-disk size: 2746.3 Kb)
0002.492 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1000 files added (on-disk size: 2746.3 Kb)
0002.498 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (3.5 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (1002) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 2746.3 Kb)
0003.875 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1100 files added (on-disk size: 4936.5 Kb)
0003.900 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1200 files added (on-disk size: 4936.5 Kb)
0003.924 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1300 files added (on-disk size: 4936.5 Kb)
0003.949 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1400 files added (on-disk size: 4936.5 Kb)
0003.981 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1500 files added (on-disk size: 4936.5 Kb)
0003.988 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (8.2 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (1503) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 4936.5 Kb)
0005.832 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1600 files added (on-disk size: 9764.4 Kb)
0005.865 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1700 files added (on-disk size: 9764.4 Kb)
0005.898 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1800 files added (on-disk size: 9764.4 Kb)
0005.931 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 1900 files added (on-disk size: 9764.4 Kb)
0005.964 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2000 files added (on-disk size: 9764.4 Kb)
0005.971 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (1.6 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (2004) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 9764.4 Kb)
0007.060 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2100 files added (on-disk size: 10444.1 Kb)
0007.098 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2200 files added (on-disk size: 10444.1 Kb)
0007.133 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2300 files added (on-disk size: 10444.1 Kb)
0007.166 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2400 files added (on-disk size: 10444.1 Kb)
0007.202 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2500 files added (on-disk size: 10444.1 Kb)
0007.213 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (14.8 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (2505) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 10444.1 Kb)
0010.657 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2600 files added (on-disk size: 15014.6 Kb)
0010.695 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2700 files added (on-disk size: 15014.6 Kb)
0010.732 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2800 files added (on-disk size: 15014.6 Kb)
0010.768 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 2900 files added (on-disk size: 15014.6 Kb)
0010.803 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3000 files added (on-disk size: 15014.6 Kb)
0010.811 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (6.7 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (3006) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 15014.6 Kb)
0013.219 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3100 files added (on-disk size: 18298.4 Kb)
0013.260 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3200 files added (on-disk size: 18298.4 Kb)
0013.302 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3300 files added (on-disk size: 18298.4 Kb)
0013.343 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3400 files added (on-disk size: 18298.4 Kb)
0013.384 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3500 files added (on-disk size: 18298.4 Kb)
0013.393 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (12.8 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (3507) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 18298.4 Kb)
0016.883 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3600 files added (on-disk size: 22986.1 Kb)
0016.929 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3700 files added (on-disk size: 22986.1 Kb)
0016.974 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3800 files added (on-disk size: 22986.1 Kb)
0017.020 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 3900 files added (on-disk size: 22986.1 Kb)
0017.065 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 4000 files added (on-disk size: 22986.1 Kb)
0017.077 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (9.1 Mb, 4229 files batched, 501 (4008) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 22986.1 Kb)
0048.235 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 4100 files added (on-disk size: 25583.7 Kb)
0049.080 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip.tmp: 4200 files added (on-disk size: 25583.7 Kb)
0066.852 (0) Created plugins zip (0) - 27242.8 Kb in 66.7 s (408.6 Kb/s) (SHA1 checksum: 39ef7e0d3790f18bec6083a807671b63009539a2)
0066.925 (0) Beginning creation of dump of themes (split every: 500 Mb)
0067.356 (0) Total entities for the zip file: 127 directories, 793 files (0 skipped as non-modified), 14.2 Mb
0067.439 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip.tmp: 100 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0067.459 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip.tmp: 200 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0067.543 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip.tmp: 300 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0067.628 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip.tmp: 400 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0067.724 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip.tmp: 500 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0067.812 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (9.5 Mb, 793 files batched, 501 (501) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 0 Kb)
0076.427 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip.tmp: 600 files added (on-disk size: 6705.3 Kb)
0076.573 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip.tmp: 700 files added (on-disk size: 6705.3 Kb)
0083.557 (0) Created themes zip (0) - 9693.9 Kb in 16.6 s (583.3 Kb/s) (SHA1 checksum: d3447e06659064849c7b62aee71ad1e8161e6e1b)
0083.635 (0) Exclusion option setting (uploads): backup*,*backups,backwpup*,wp-clone
0083.642 (0) Looking for candidates to back up in: /home/git/projects/expandintheusa.com/wp-content/uploads
0083.672 (0) finding files: wp-less-cache: adding to list (1)
0083.681 (0) finding files: db-backup: adding to list (2)
0083.713 (0) finding files: 2015: adding to list (3)
0083.722 (0) finding files: 2014: adding to list (4)
0083.730 (0) Beginning creation of dump of uploads (split every: 500 Mb)
0085.808 (0) Total entities for the zip file: 23 directories, 2220 files (0 skipped as non-modified), 105.6 Mb
0085.933 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 100 files added (on-disk size: 0 Kb)
0085.994 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 25 Mb added on this batch (25 Mb, 2220 files batched, 196 (196) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 0 Kb)
0114.011 (0) A useful amount of data was added after this amount of zip processing: 30.9 s (normalised: 30.9 s, rate: 829.5 Kb/s)
0114.060 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 200 files added (on-disk size: 22035 Kb)
0114.076 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 300 files added (on-disk size: 22035 Kb)
0114.169 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 25 Mb added on this batch (28 Mb, 2220 files batched, 151 (347) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 22035 Kb)
0139.006 (0) A useful amount of data was added after this amount of zip processing: 25.9 s (normalised: 23.1 s, rate: 1108.2 Kb/s)
0139.024 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 400 files added (on-disk size: 48732.1 Kb)
0139.133 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 500 files added (on-disk size: 48732.1 Kb)
0139.226 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 600 files added (on-disk size: 48732.1 Kb)
0139.435 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 700 files added (on-disk size: 48732.1 Kb)
0139.568 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 800 files added (on-disk size: 48732.1 Kb)
0139.583 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 500 files added on this batch (15.3 Mb, 2220 files batched, 501 (848) added so far); re-opening (prior size: 48732.1 Kb)
0162.869 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 900 files added (on-disk size: 63565.8 Kb)
0163.347 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1000 files added (on-disk size: 63565.8 Kb)
0163.476 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1100 files added (on-disk size: 63565.8 Kb)
0163.954 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1200 files added (on-disk size: 63565.8 Kb)
0165.147 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 2.0 seconds have passed since the last write (15.2 Mb, 448 (1296) files added so far); re-opening (prior size: 63565.8 Kb)
0236.862 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1300 files added (on-disk size: 78778.2 Kb)
0237.705 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1400 files added (on-disk size: 78778.2 Kb)
0237.949 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1500 files added (on-disk size: 78778.2 Kb)
0239.024 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1600 files added (on-disk size: 78778.2 Kb)
0239.143 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 2.0 seconds have passed since the last write (8.6 Mb, 312 (1608) files added so far); re-opening (prior size: 78778.2 Kb)
0310.277 (1) Opened log file at time: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 22:09:22 -0500 on http://www.expandintheusa.com
0310.633 (1) UpdraftPlus WordPress backup plugin (https://updraftplus.com): 1.11.17 WP: 4.3.1 PHP: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 (Linux lucid 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686) MySQL: 5.5.35 Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) safe_mode: 0 max_execution_time: 900 memory_limit: 1024M (used: 3.3M | 3.5M) multisite: N mcrypt: N LANG: C ZipArchive::addFile: Y
0310.872 (1) Free space on disk containing Updraft's temporary directory: 12036.3 Mb
0311.353 (0) The time we have been running (310.3) is approaching the resumption interval (300) - increasing resumption interval to 341
0311.483 (1) Backup run: resumption=1, nonce=5811117ce9f5, begun at=1448334251 (312s ago), job type=backup, previous check-in=236.6s
0312.652 (1) Scheduling a resumption (2) after 300 seconds (1448334864) in case this run gets aborted
0312.773 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1700 files added (on-disk size: 87266.2 Kb)
0313.253 (1) Checking if we have a zip executable available
0313.490 (1) Creation of backups of directories: had begun; will resume
0313.616 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1800 files added (on-disk size: 87266.2 Kb)
0313.832 (1) Beginning creation of dump of plugins (split every: 500 Mb)
0313.946 (1) backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-plugins.zip: this file has already been created (age: 250 s)
0314.185 (0) Adding batch to zip file (UpdraftPlus_ZipArchive): over 2.0 seconds have passed since the last write (4.8 Mb, 197 (1805) files added so far); re-opening (prior size: 87266.2 Kb)
0314.674 (1) Beginning creation of dump of themes (split every: 500 Mb)
0314.905 (1) backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-themes.zip: this file has already been created (age: 232 s)
0315.753 (1) Exclusion option setting (uploads): backup*,*backups,backwpup*,wp-clone
0316.226 (1) Looking for candidates to back up in: /home/git/projects/expandintheusa.com/wp-content/uploads
0316.348 (1) finding files: wp-less-cache: adding to list (1)
0316.466 (1) finding files: db-backup: adding to list (2)
0316.474 (1) finding files: 2015: adding to list (3)
0316.591 (1) finding files: 2014: adding to list (4)
0316.709 (1) Beginning creation of dump of uploads (split every: 500 Mb)
0317.193 (1) Terminate: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp exists with activity within the last 30 seconds (time_mod=1448334565, time_now=1448334568, diff=3, size=87266.2Kb). This likely means that another UpdraftPlus run is at work; so we will exit.
0317.429 (1) Rescheduling resumption 2: moving to 420 seconds from now (1448334989)
0317.667 (1) To decrease the likelihood of overlaps, increasing resumption interval to: 300 + 120 = 420
0330.437 (0) The time we have been running (330.3) is approaching the resumption interval (341) - increasing resumption interval to 361
0330.649 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 1900 files added (on-disk size: 91962.1 Kb)
0330.834 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 2000 files added (on-disk size: 91962.1 Kb)
0331.234 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 2100 files added (on-disk size: 91962.1 Kb)
0331.603 (0) Zip: backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-uploads.zip.tmp: 2200 files added (on-disk size: 91962.1 Kb)
0354.505 (0) The time we have been running (354.4) is approaching the resumption interval (361) - increasing resumption interval to 385
0377.425 (0) Created uploads zip (0) - 100523.7 Kb in 293.7 s (342.3 Kb/s) (SHA1 checksum: eef1d19e80dc3e15c013a3796a8a166e1fb625fd)
0377.669 (0) Beginning backup of other directories found in the content directory (index: 0)
0377.785 (0) Exclusion option setting (others): upgrade,cache,updraft,backup*,*backups,mysql.sql
0377.910 (0) Looking for candidates to back up in: /home/git/projects/expandintheusa.com/wp-content
0378.265 (0) finding files: upgrade: skipping: excluded by options
0378.273 (0) finding files: tablepress-custom.min.css: adding to list (1)
0378.385 (0) finding files: tablepress-combined.min.css: adding to list (2)
0378.395 (0) finding files: tablepress-custom.css: adding to list (3)
0378.631 (0) finding files: plugins: skipping: this is the plugins directory
0378.745 (0) finding files: uploads: skipping: this is the uploads directory
0378.753 (0) finding files: index.php: adding to list (4)
0378.865 (0) finding files: themes: skipping: this is the themes directory
0378.873 (0) finding files: updraft: skipping: this is the updraft directory
0378.985 (0) finding files: backupwordpress-30c13ede3d-backups: skipping: excluded by options (glob)
0378.993 (0) finding files: backupwordpress-30c13ede3d-backups: skipping: excluded by options (glob)
0379.585 (0) Total entities for the zip file: 0 directories, 4 files (0 skipped as non-modified), 0 Mb
0380.192 (0) The time we have been running (380.1) is approaching the resumption interval (385) - increasing resumption interval to 411
0380.431 (0) Created others zip (0) - 3.6 Kb in 1.2 s (3 Kb/s) (SHA1 checksum: 137d9f6a0c30ef796dfed437f7ba162f85400d6a)
0381.026 (0) Saving backup status to database (elements: 8)
0381.257 (0) Beginning creation of database dump (WordPress DB)
0381.380 (0) Testing: /usr/bin/mysqldump
0382.154 (0) Working binary mysqldump found: /usr/bin/mysqldump
0382.280 (0) Table wp_options: Total expected rows (approximate): 1576
0382.572 (0) Table wp_options: Total rows added: 402 in 0.25 seconds
0382.683 (0) Table wp_options: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_options.table.gz - 798 Kb)
0382.732 (0) The time we have been running (382.7) is approaching the resumption interval (411) - increasing resumption interval to 413
0382.785 (0) Table wp_users: Total expected rows (approximate): 3
0382.817 (0) Table wp_users: Total rows added: 3 in 0.00 seconds
0382.851 (0) Table wp_users: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_users.table.gz - 1.6 Kb)
0382.903 (0) Table wp_usermeta: Total expected rows (approximate): 106
0382.918 (0) Table wp_usermeta: Total rows added: 106 in 0.00 seconds
0382.984 (0) Table wp_usermeta: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_usermeta.table.gz - 12.1 Kb)
0383.031 (0) Table wp_commentmeta: Total expected rows (approximate): 53
0383.041 (0) Table wp_commentmeta: Total rows added: 53 in 0.00 seconds
0383.051 (0) Table wp_commentmeta: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_commentmeta.table.gz - 2.9 Kb)
0383.131 (0) The time we have been running (383.1) is approaching the resumption interval (413) - increasing resumption interval to 414
0383.200 (0) Table wp_comments: Total expected rows (approximate): 78
0383.217 (0) Table wp_comments: Total rows added: 53 in 0.01 seconds
0383.319 (0) Table wp_comments: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_comments.table.gz - 84.9 Kb)
0383.359 (0) Table wp_links: Total expected rows (approximate): 0
0383.393 (0) Table wp_links: Total rows added: 0 in 0.00 seconds
0383.426 (0) Table wp_links: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_links.table.gz - 1.3 Kb)
0383.481 (0) Table wp_postmeta: Total expected rows (approximate): 35660
0386.024 (0) Table wp_postmeta: binary mysqldump finished (writes: 36) in 2.50 seconds
0386.092 (0) Table wp_postmeta: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_postmeta.table.gz - 4118.8 Kb)
0386.155 (0) The time we have been running (386.1) is approaching the resumption interval (414) - increasing resumption interval to 417
0386.204 (0) Table wp_posts: Total expected rows (approximate): 6303
0408.501 (0) Table wp_posts: Total rows added: 5165 in 22.12 seconds
0408.643 (0) Table wp_posts: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_posts.table.gz - 75759.6 Kb)
0408.761 (0) The time we have been running (408.7) is approaching the resumption interval (417) - increasing resumption interval to 439
0408.858 (0) Table wp_term_relationships: Total expected rows (approximate): 5202
0409.811 (0) Table wp_term_relationships: Total rows added: 5144 in 0.94 seconds
0409.846 (0) Table wp_term_relationships: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_term_relationships.table.gz - 84.3 Kb)
0409.891 (0) The time we have been running (409.9) is approaching the resumption interval (439) - increasing resumption interval to 440
0409.940 (0) Table wp_term_taxonomy: Total expected rows (approximate): 819
0410.188 (0) Table wp_term_taxonomy: Total rows added: 749 in 0.24 seconds
0410.266 (0) Table wp_term_taxonomy: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_term_taxonomy.table.gz - 28.5 Kb)
0410.320 (0) The time we have been running (410.3) is approaching the resumption interval (440) - increasing resumption interval to 441
0410.408 (0) Table wp_terms: Total expected rows (approximate): 836
0410.618 (0) Table wp_terms: Total rows added: 749 in 0.21 seconds
0410.687 (0) Table wp_terms: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_terms.table.gz - 35.1 Kb)
0410.739 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_404_links: Total expected rows (approximate): 4864
0413.857 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_404_links: Total rows added: 4864 in 3.09 seconds
0413.892 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_404_links: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_WP_SEO_404_links.table.gz - 876.7 Kb)
0413.938 (0) The time we have been running (413.9) is approaching the resumption interval (441) - increasing resumption interval to 444
0413.991 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Cache: Total expected rows (approximate): 28
0414.036 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Cache: Total rows added: 28 in 0.04 seconds
0414.044 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Cache: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_WP_SEO_Cache.table.gz - 1.3 Kb)
0414.094 (0) The time we have been running (414.1) is approaching the resumption interval (444) - increasing resumption interval to 445
0414.144 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Redirection: Total expected rows (approximate): 1
0414.157 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Redirection: Total rows added: 1 in 0.00 seconds
0414.203 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Redirection: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_WP_SEO_Redirection.table.gz - 1.6 Kb)
0414.253 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Redirection_LOG: Total expected rows (approximate): 6
0414.282 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Redirection_LOG: Total rows added: 6 in 0.02 seconds
0414.312 (0) Table wp_WP_SEO_Redirection_LOG: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_WP_SEO_Redirection_LOG.table.gz - 2.9 Kb)
0414.372 (0) Table wp_attendees: Total expected rows (approximate): 223
0414.439 (0) Table wp_attendees: Total rows added: 186 in 0.06 seconds
0414.532 (0) Table wp_attendees: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_attendees.table.gz - 23.9 Kb)
0414.587 (0) Table wp_cntctfrm_field: Total expected rows (approximate): 13
0414.596 (0) Table wp_cntctfrm_field: Total rows added: 13 in 0.00 seconds
0414.636 (0) Table wp_cntctfrm_field: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_cntctfrm_field.table.gz - 0.8 Kb)
0414.668 (0) Table wp_duplicator_packages: Total expected rows (approximate): 1
0414.711 (0) Table wp_duplicator_packages: Total rows added: 1 in 0.00 seconds
0414.747 (0) Table wp_duplicator_packages: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_duplicator_packages.table.gz - 3.4 Kb)
0415.162 (0) The time we have been running (415) is approaching the resumption interval (445) - increasing resumption interval to 446
0415.608 (0) Table wp_hidemysiteSecure: Total expected rows (approximate): 7
0415.616 (0) Table wp_hidemysiteSecure: Total rows added: 7 in 0.00 seconds
0415.681 (0) Table wp_hidemysiteSecure: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_hidemysiteSecure.table.gz - 0.9 Kb)
0415.878 (0) Table wp_mc4wp_log: Total expected rows (approximate): 103
0415.894 (0) Table wp_mc4wp_log: Total rows added: 94 in 0.01 seconds
0416.002 (0) Table wp_mc4wp_log: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_mc4wp_log.table.gz - 17.5 Kb)
0416.320 (0) The time we have been running (416) is approaching the resumption interval (446) - increasing resumption interval to 447
0416.676 (0) Table wp_nm_mc_forms: Total expected rows (approximate): 0
0416.683 (0) Table wp_nm_mc_forms: Total rows added: 0 in 0.00 seconds
0416.798 (0) Table wp_nm_mc_forms: finishing file (backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_nm_mc_forms.table.gz - 0.6 Kb)
0416.971 (0) PHP function is disabled; abort expected: gzopen
0417.075 (0) backup_2015-11-23-2204_Expand_in_the_USA_5811117ce9f5-db-table-wp_options.table.gz (1/21): adding to final database dump
```

Comment: Is your AWS running on Ubuntu by any chance?

Comment: @Michael Could you explain how I can check that? From what I vaguely recall, the answer is no but I can't remember why I believe that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is know for the updraft plugin backup functionality for Ubuntu. The working solution is provided in the [wordpress support discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-function-is-disabled-abort-expected-gzopen-updraft):

Solution:

just add this to your wp-config.php, to bring the gzopen() function back:

```
if (!function_exists('gzopen')) {
   function gzopen($filename , $mode, $use_include_path = 0 ) { 
      return gzopen64($filename, $mode, $use_include_path); 
   }
}
```